# join 2 tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Here is the configuration I am starting with:

```
DROP TABLE  ruleset1;
CREATE TABLE  ruleset1  (id int not null unique,score_rule1 float default 0.0,score_rule2 float default 0.0,score_rule3 float default 0.0);
DROP TABLE  ruleset2;
CREATE TABLE  ruleset2  (id int not null unique,score_rule1 float default 0.0,score_rule2 float default 0.0,score_rule3 float default 0.0);

insert into ruleset1 (id, score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3) values (0,0.8,0,0);
insert into ruleset1 (id, score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3) values (1,0,0.1,0);
insert into ruleset2 (id, score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3) values (0,0,0,0.3);
insert into ruleset2 (id, score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3) values (2,0,0.2,0);
```

what I have is this now is 2 tables
ruleset1:

```
| ID | SCORE_RULE1 | SCORE_RULE2 | SCORE_RULE3 
================================================
| 0  |    0.8      |     0       |     0     
| 1  |    0        |     0.1     |     0
```

and ruleset2:

```
| ID | SCORE_RULE1 | SCORE_RULE2 | SCORE_RULE3 
================================================
| 0  |    0        |     0       |     0.3     
| 2  |    0        |     0.2     |     0
```

and I want to outer join them and calculate the mean of non zero columns, like this:

```
| ID | Average  
================
| 0  |    0.55 
| 1  |    0.1 
| 2  |    0.2
```

My current query is:

```
select * from ruleset1 full outer join ruleset2 on ruleset1.id = ruleset2.id;
```

which gives an ugly result:

```
| ID | SCORE_RULE1 | SCORE_RULE2 | SCORE_RULE3 | ID | SCORE_RULE1 | SCORE_RULE2 | SCORE_RULE3
============================================================================================
| 0  |     .8      |       0     |      0      | 0  |      0      |      0      |   .3
| -  |     -       |       -     |      -      | 2  |      0      |      .2     |   0
| 1  |     0       |       .1    |      0      | -  |      -      |      -      |   -
```

Can anyone help with a better query please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, then don't you need to use the avg() function somewhere?  Your table design looks flawed.  Why do you need two tables that store the same thing?  Add a ruleset column to one table.

Comment: Do you simply ignore the zeroes when calcuating the average?

Comment: yes i simply ignore zeros, and for the avg() function, it doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Can you explain how you get `0.55 - 0.1 - 0.2` , you know for those of us who doesnt play with statistic so much since university :)

Comment: I don't get it, why do you ignore 0 values? That's no average then, is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "outer join" - do you mean UNION ALL and then group by ID and take the sum in each column? "outer join" sounds like the wrong tool for this.

Comment: "ugly" and "better" are subjective. tell us what you want, and tell us what else you tried. Are you familiar with the different types of joins?

Comment: JuanCarlosOropeza, @mathguy: you're right I've mistaken when I said average :) let's say "the average of non zero values" instead. so 0.55 = (0.8 + 0.3) / 2 (non zero values) || 0.2 = 0.2 / 1  and finally 0.1 = 0.1 / 1

Comment: So you don't want to combine the values for id=0 in any way, you just want to put them all in one bag, remove the 0 values, and take the average of what is left? Then it may be best to unpivot your two original tables, then union all and then use the AVG() aggregate function.

Comment: Also, it would be best to edit your question so it is clear to anyone who reads it (the clarification shouldn't just be in comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course `avg` doesn't ignore zeroes, only NULLs, thus `NULLIF(column, 0)` could be used.

But as you got denormalized data you can simply normalize it on-the-fly:

```
select id, avg(score)
from
 (
    select id, score_rule1   score 
        from ruleset1 where score_rule1 <> 0
    union all 
    select id, score_rule2 from ruleset1 where score_rule2 <> 0
    union all
    select id, score_rule3 from ruleset1 where score_rule3 <> 0
    union all 
    select id, score_rule1 from ruleset2 where score_rule1 <> 0
    union all 
    select id, score_rule2 from ruleset2 where score_rule2 <> 0
    union all 
    select id, score_rule3 from ruleset2 where score_rule3 <> 0
 ) dt
group by id;
```

To avoid five Unions you could use only one and do some additional logic:

```
select id, sum(score) / sum(score_count)
from
 (
    select id, score_rule1 + score_rule2 + score_rule3   score,
       case when score_rule1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
       case when score_rule2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
       case when score_rule3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end   score_count
    from ruleset1 

    union all 

    select id, score_rule1 + score_rule2 + score_rule3 score,
       case when score_rule1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
       case when score_rule2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
       case when score_rule3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end   score_count
    from ruleset2
 ) dt
group by id;
```

This assumes there are no NULLs in the core_rule columns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to ask you if this is "heavy" in execution time? or is there a quicker way?

Comment: @msalem Looks very efficient. But you can try it and look the `EXPLAIN PLAN` probably will need include index for each `score_rule` on both tables.

Comment: @msalem: I added a 2nd query to Select only once per table, simply check actual resource usage if this is more efficient.

Comment: If you want remove union my version only have a `JOIN`, but again you should test with [**EXPLAIN PLAN**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) to see what version is the fastest.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Too much `Coalesce`, I prefer `Union All` over a `Full Outer Join` ;-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but what about the columns being "hardcoded"? does that suppose I have to know all the columns names in advance?  (In th case, I can't get this step automated)

Comment: @msalem: Of course you need to know the names of the columns you're goin to average. If it's something like *all columns after the first one* you must create this list with Dynamic SQL using metadata like `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with PostgreSQL that you could adapt with Oracle (sorry, SQLFiddle's Oracle isn't cooperating). Thanks to Juan Carlos Oropeza's suggestion, the code below runs on Oracle well: http://rextester.com/DVP59353

```
select
  r.id,
  sum(coalesce(r1.score_rule1,0) + 
      coalesce(r1.score_rule2,0) + 
      coalesce(r1.score_rule3,0) +
      coalesce(r2.score_rule1,0) + 
      coalesce(r2.score_rule2,0) + 
      coalesce(r2.score_rule3,0)
      )
      /
  sum(case when coalesce(r1.score_rule1,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when coalesce(r1.score_rule2,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when coalesce(r1.score_rule3,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when coalesce(r2.score_rule1,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when coalesce(r2.score_rule2,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when coalesce(r2.score_rule3,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Average

from

  (select id from ruleset1
  union
  select id from ruleset2) r

left join ruleset1 r1 on r.id = r1.id
left join ruleset2 r2 on r.id = r2.id

group by r.id
```

SQLFiddle with PostgreSQL version is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/24e3f/1.

This example combines id from both tables using a `union`. Doing so allows the same ID in both ruleset1 and ruleset2 to appear just once in the result. `r` is an alias given to this generated table.

All the `id`s are then left joined with both tables. During the summation process, it is possible that the NULL values resulting from left join may impact the result. So the NULLs are coalesced to zero in the math.

Comment: try [**rexter**](http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler) also have mysql, postgres and MSSql

Comment: Sweet! Thank you, @JuanCarlosOropeza. I didn't know rexter existed. Much appreciated.

Comment: I still use `sqlFiddle` because has the `Text to DDL`  function. But then move the DDL to rexter. btw checking your site, pls make up your mind, 3 reason to move from git to svn and 3 reason to move from svn to git.

Answer (score 0):

dnoeth is the easy and clean answer.

here I was just playing with `COALESCE` and `NVL2`

```
select COALESCE(r.ID, s.ID),
  COALESCE(r.score_rule1, 0) + 
  COALESCE(r.score_rule2, 0) + 
  COALESCE(r.score_rule3, 0) +
  COALESCE(s.score_rule1, 0) + 
  COALESCE(s.score_rule2, 0) + 
  COALESCE(s.score_rule3, 0) as sum,

  NVL2(r.score_rule1, 0, 1) + 
  NVL2(r.score_rule2, 0, 1) + 
  NVL2(r.score_rule3, 0, 1) + 
  NVL2(s.score_rule1, 0, 1) + 
  NVL2(s.score_rule2, 0, 1) + 
  NVL2(s.score_rule3, 0, 1) as tot

from ruleset1 r
full outer join ruleset2 s
  on ruleset1.id = ruleset2.id;
```

Then your avg is `sum/tot`

Answer (score 0):

`union all` your two tables, unpivot, change the zeros into null with `nullif`, and use standard `avg()` aggregate function:

```
select id, avg(nullif(value, 0)) as avg_value from (
  select * from ruleset1
  union all
  select * from ruleset2
)
unpivot ( value for column_name in (score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3))
group by id
order by id
;

        ID  AVG_VALUE
---------- ----------
         0        .55
         1         .1
         2         .2
```

Comment: it seems that this query is very efficient, but what if one of the tables does not have the 3 columns (score_rule1, score_rule2, score_rule3) ?

Comment: @msalem - I can only answer the question you asked. How can I know what else you may have in your real-life example? What do you mean if one of the tables doesn't have the 3 columns? What does it have, just one column with the ID?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT s.id, AVG(s.score)
FROM(
SELECT id,score_rule1+score_rule2+score_rule3 as score
FROM ruleset2
UNION ALL
SELECT id,(score_rule1+score_rule2+score_rule3) as score
FROM ruleset1) s

group by s.id
```

Comment: close but op need avg of non-zero values.

Comment: need to explain what your answer is. Just posting code isn't necessarily helpful.